# Free shipping on mimimum item amount

Tags: magento-1, shipping, free-shipping, items

I am looking for a way to make free shipping if the customer orders a minimum amount of 12 items or over.

I have not found a way to do this anywhere, so i am counting on that someone here can point me in the direction i need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Magento - Wiki - Shopping Cart Price Rule Free SHipping](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes#free_shipping)

Then change the condition to:

[image]